# Efficient way of checking data in mongo and creating them if they don't exist

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to find a efficient way to search in mongo to find whether new data(for example phone number as below) which is provided exists, if they don't exists i want to insert them into another collection.

Search whether the `phone number` in array [123456789, 15, 20] associated to user exists if `phone no.15, 20` don't exist then i need to identify some way that they don't exist in the database collection, so i can insert into another collection. I'm trying to find solution for my requirement in most efficient way so i don't hit the database a lot.

### User Collection

```
{
    "_id" : "mJPqhyyGoeyfa3p2w",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-11-30T22:33:27.649Z"),
    "phone" : {
        "number" : "123456789",
        "verified" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
        "picture" : "xx",
            "name" : "User IOS Mobile"
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I understand you want to insert a document with those values if they don't exist. Right?

Comment: Yes, insert into another Collection.

Comment: collection or document?

Comment: If you provide an array, you want to find out which of those in the array individually don't exist? or every value in the array?

Comment: @user3100115 i will have another collection name LineNoNotFound where i want to insert the LineNo's that were not found.

Comment: @inspired Only those in the array individually don't exist.

Comment: so document in the new collection will look like this : `{'lineNo': [25, 20]`} or two documents like this `{lineNo: 25}, {lineNo: 20`}?

Comment: @user3100115 First one is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert all elements that are not in the 'lineNo' array into another collection then you need to use the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) operator and the [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference) operator. Of course the [`.aggregate()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) method  provides access to the aggregation pipeline.

You will then use ["bulk"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operations for the insertion.

```
var bulk = db.LineNoNotFound.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;

db.inventory.aggregate([
    { '$group': {
        '_id': null,
        'phones': {'$push': '$phone.number'}
    }},  
    { '$project': {
          'notFound': {
             '$setDifference': [ [ 5, 15, 20, 25 ], '$phones' ]
         }
    }},
    { '$match': { 'notFound.0': { '$exists': true } } }
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.notFound.forEach(function(num) {
        bulk.insert( { 'lineNo': num } );
        count++;
    });
    if (count % 100 === 0) {
         bulk.execute();
         bulk = db.LineNoNotFound.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if (count > 0)  bulk.execute();
```